# How to convert JSON object with unidirectional Java Object using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization, jackson

I have two entities called client and quote.

Client having many quotes.

Many Quotes having singe client.

```
@Entity
class Client
{
int c_id;
String clientName;
@OneToMany
List<Quote> quotes;
}

@Entity
class Quote
{
int q_id;
String item;
@ManyToOne
Client client;
}
```

JSON Object Request Param :

```
{
  "clientName":"ABC pvt Ltd",
  "quotes" :[
    {
      "item":"A"
    },
    {
      "item":"B"
    }
    {
      "item":"C"
    }   
   ]
}
```

I want serialize above Request param to Client Object.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Client cli = om.convervalue(x,Client.class);

session.save(cli);
```

If I run the above the code 
**Client having List of Quote Reference**. 
But **Quote class Client Reference is null**.

So if i want to achieve this i did it manually.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Client cli = om.convervalue(x,Client.class);

List<Quote> quotes = cli.getQuotes;

for(int i=0;i<quotes.size();i++)
{
  Quote qu = quotes.get(i);
  qu.setClient(cli);
}

session.save(cli);
```

The above code works fine.
 
How to do it automatically with Jackson Library.
 
Is there any annotation is do it?

**Basically Two Way Relationship Serialization is Needed**?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below annotation to map your json based on their hibernate mapping with @JsonManagedReference & @JsonBackReference

```
@Entity
class Client
{
int c_id;
String clientName;
@OneToMany
@JsonManagedReference
List<Quote> quotes;
}

@Entity
class Quote
{
int q_id;
String item;
@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
Client client;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Client.class` add getters/setters or make fields public.
Then try below:

```
      String json = "{\"clientName\":\"John\","+"\"quotes\":[{\"item\":\"A\"},{\"item\":\"B\"}]}";
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      Client client = mapper.readValue(json,Client.class);
      System.out.println(client);
```